# Laxman v/s Parshuram?

Tags: ramayana, rama, parashurama, lakshmana

When Ram pulled apart the Shiv Dhanush, a conversation took place between Parshuram and Laxman, I had a concern that, if a battle have had happened, **who could have won the individual battle?**

As they both claimed to be the strongest.

[image]

Comment: Lord Parshuram is himself Vishnu Avatar, trained by Lord Shiva and has big powers, compared to Laxman who was kind of "angry young man" at that moment, and it seems that Lord Ram at that moment came to his rescue as he might knew the result of battle between Lord Parshuram and Laxman might result in Laxman's defeat, this is what I think